# Resource not found in Jersey (Error 404)

Tags: java, ajax, rest, maven, jersey

I am making an AJAX call to a Jersey resource through JavaScript where class is mapped to /books and a GET method to /allBooks. This is the code for AJAX call:

```
function libBooks(){

    alert("Inside js");
    //The above alert is displayed

    var requestData = {
            "dataType":  "application/json",
            "type":   "GET",
            "url":    "http://localhost:8080/library/rest/books/allBooks/"
    };

    var request = $.ajax(requestData);
    alert("Ajax call made");
    //The above alert is displayed

    request.success(function(data) {

        alert("Inside done function");
        //The above alert is not displayed
        var dataReceived =data.listOfBooks;
        var numOfItems = dataReceived.length;
        alert(numOfItems);

    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, status, errorMessage) {
        if((errorMessage = $.trim(errorMessage)) === "") {
            alert("An unspecified error occurred.  Check the server error log for details.");
        }
        else {
            alert("An error occurred:  " + errorMessage);
        }
    });

}
```

In JSP I have a link like this:

```
<p>List of books in library  <a href="" onclick="libBooks();">Click Here</a></p>
```

And here is my BookResource:

```
@Path("/books")
public class BookResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/allBooks")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAllBooks() {

        BooksHelper bookHelper = new BooksHelper();
        ArrayList<Book> listOfBooks = bookHelper.getListOfBooks();

        ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.status(Status.OK);
        responseBuilder.entity(listOfBooks);

        Response response = responseBuilder.build();
        return response;            
    }
}
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.sudhanshu</groupId>
    <artifactId>library</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>library</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>library</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
      <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I am not sure how mapping in pom.xml works as I am using Maven for the first time. Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>org.sudhanshu.library</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When I get to the URL:  http://localhost:8080/library/rest/books/allBooks , it says resource not found 404. I think the problem might be in web.xml REST request entry point and my mapping in Resource. Also, please suggest if URL in my ajax request is correct or not. I have tried various things but none of them are working. For now I just want an alert that shows that ajax call was successful.Here is my directory structure: Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at here

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>org.sudhanshu.library</param-value>
</init-param>
```

You're specifying the package(s) to scan is `org.sudhanshu.library`. Looking at the image of your project structure, that package is empty. The package you *should* be scanning is `com.resources`

Second thing (unrelated to the 404, but will be the next problem) is you need a JSON provider. You can see in the generated pom.xml file they give you a hint

```
<!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
</dependency>
-->
```

You need to un-comment that dependency. Also I would change the dependency from `jersey-media-moxy` to `jersey-media-json-jackson`. IMO Jackson works a lot better than MOXy in many aspects.

Comment: It Works!! Could you help me explain what that init param means in this case? From what I read online, it is used if we want to send parameters to a servlet from web.xml. I cannot put this is perspective in this case. Will appreciate it. Thanks once again.

Comment: Jersey allows you to provide a comma separated list of packages you want it to scan to pick up classes annotated with `@Path` and `@Provider` to register in the application. Since you're initially scanning an empty package, your resource (@Path annotated class) is not registered

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet . You have been a great help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me find out what was my problem: I was having the same issue (resource not found) and I tried to establish my `<param-value>` tag with only the name of the package where my resource is (not nameOfMyApp.myResource).
I think it could be helpful to know it as few colleagues where having also the same mistake as I was.

Comment: Just a note, there is another init-param `jersey.config.server.provider.classnames`. You can specify a comma separated list of classes to register. Some times it is useful for Jersey features which are not annotated with `@Provider` or you have third party resources and providers you want to register.